# RedirectPermanent : How to manage 301 redirection domain name

Tags: redirect

I'd like to redirect `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com`

I've try in my .htaccess :

```
RedirectPermanent http://example.com http://www.example.com
```

It doesn't work.
How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways but I'll explain you some of them:

**1. Redirect using RewriteRule module - mod_rewrite:**

> Options +FollowSymLinks
>
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

or

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^www.(.*) [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1   [R=301,L]

**2. Redirect using Scripts:**

*PHP redirect:*

```
 <?php 
header(“HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently”); 
header(“Location:
http://www.newdomain.ru/newdir/newpage.htm”); 
exit(); 
?>
```

*ASP.NET redirect:*

```
<script runat=“server”>
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Response.Status = “301 Moved Permanently”;
Response.AddHeader(“Location”,“http://www.new-url.com”);
}
</script>
```

*Ruby on Rails:*

```
def old_action
headers[“Status”] = “301 Moved Permanently”
redirect_to “http://www.new-url.com/”
end
```

*If you need more info, please write me down!

Best regards*